# How to customize background image and youtube window in Purity III - Features Intro 1

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, t3-framework, purity-iii, joomlart

I want to change background in [purity template with Features Intro 1 layout](http://purity-iii.demo.joomlart.com/index.php/layout/new-layouts/features-intro) from plain blue to image in this area:
[image]

I tried inspect element but couldn't find any css that responsible for this style. Can you help me figure this out how to change the background from color to picture?

And also, how to change the youtube link from that page? I already look at the Purity Video module but there's no youtube link. Any idea where should I find to change the youtube link?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

- **To change the background you want:**
  If you haven't already, create empty file `custom.css` in folder `/templates/purity_iii/css/` then add to it following selector and adjust it to your liking:

  > .row-feature.row-feature-primary {
  >   background: url('your_image_path') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  >   }
- **Regarding that YouTube video:**
  You are already looking at correct module, i.e. Custom HTML module `Purity III video` in position `masthead`, but the reason you are not seeing full HTML code lays in the fact that by default TinyMCE editor HIDES `<iframe>` tags (and `<script><applet>` tags too).
  So, either:

  - go to Global Configuration and choose `No Editor` for default editor,
  - OR go to `Extensions | Plugins`, click `Search Tools` button, from `Select Type` dropdown choose `editors`, click on `Editor - TinyMCE` and from `Prohibited Elements` textfield delete `iframe`. That way you can use TinyMCE as default editor and see YouTube iframe in it.
  - in the unfortunate case that you saved your changes to that module before changing above plugin settings, and TinyMCE deleted iframe, do not despair - read the secton
    `5.5 Masthead configuration` on the last link in my answer.
- **Word of advice: RTFM!**
  In order to prevent "Great Hair Loss" in dealing with "Easy To Customize" templates from Joomla Template Giants (JoomlArt, RocketTheme, etc...), you'd better invest some time to find and read as much as possible of their documentation, prior to start working on them.
  In your case, there are tons of Tutorials on JA site for their legendary Purity template:
  [Purity III Docs](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/purity-iii)
  [Purity III Default Layouts](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/purity-iii/layout-in-details)
  [Purity III Features Intro 1 layout](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/purity-iii/layout-in-details#features-layout)
  etc...